# Initialize a boolean array element to be true?

Tags: java, arrays

How to initialize a single element to be true rather than initializing the whole array.

```
    do {
        if (flightClass == 1) {
            Arrays.fill(seats, true);
        } else if (flightClass == 2) {
            Arrays.fill(seats, true);
        }
    } while (i <= 10);
```

My approach was to do this....

```
    do {
        if (flightClass == 1) {
            int enterSeat = input.nextInt();
            Arrays.fill(seats[enterSeat], true);
        } else if (flightClass == 2) {
            Arrays.fill(seats, true);
        }
    } while (i <= 10);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
Arrays.fill(seats[enterSeat], true);
```

Simply do this:

```
seats[enterSeat] = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply write

```
seats[enterSeat] = true
```

to set a single array element.

Comment: It is, however, strange to put everything into the while loop, and it is even more strange not to change `i` inside the loop. Are you sure your logic is correct?